# How to update the UI without injecting UI dependencies?

Tags: winforms

Consider the following text book example class:

```
class Worker
{
   public void SomeUpdateMethod(SomeObject input)
   { 
      // Some long running process, candidate for a multi-threaded operation
   }
}
```

Since Worker class knows nothing about the UI, it can be considered reusable.

However: Once we want to update the UI - Now the Business Object (in this case Worker class) - Needs to be aware of the UI elements it needs to update. This might be a label or progress bar.

It seems like an anti-pattern. And breaks a clean layer (Business Logic and Presentation) structure.

How has this problem been solved? A small example or just the high level theory will do.

Comment: "Once we want to update the UI - Business Object (in this case Worker class) - Needs to be aware of the UI elements it needs to update". why?? wpf for example happily relies on `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, implemented in objects. business object can generate event[s] when its state changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events and Delegates are the way to do this.